# Xpoo Go does no open on Simulator with MacOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying out react native on my M1 MacBook and I am getting this when I launch the Xcode IOS simulator.
I do not have any errors in the console and the QR code scan on multiple devices is working perfectly.

Here is what happens:
[open and close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2Qz0.gif)

here is my console:

[My console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFTJT.png)

Comment: it looks like your app is crashing it (see the error from your console image above the reloads). try creating a brand new app and loading it - does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Cassandra and everything is working as expected.

I got the steps to install Cassandra  from [here](https://gist.github.com/ssmereka/e41d4ad053a547611ba7ef1dac4cc826)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating xcode. A while back I also experienced problems with xcode on mac and after updating xcode everything was working again.

Comment: Yes, 
I am using the latest version of Xcode